# How to identify circular reference(s) in huge project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have a huge ecommerce project (WSP) I inherited so it's nearly 800k lines of brownfield code with many components.  When I compile I unerringly get a warning about circular references and the compile stops.  If I build again it completes and runs.

I have no idea where to start looking for this circular reference.  I understand what they are, just not how to find a needle like that in the haystack of my project.

How does one identify the cause of a circular reference without going line by line?

Comment: Check each projects references and see if any project references one that references itself?

Comment: The error will tell you what projects are causing a circular reference. On the right side of the error, you should see a Project. If you click on the references for that project, it will have a yellow triangle under it. Those are your circular (or other errors) references. +TheLethalCoder, he speciificaly states that the project is huge. That's such a long winded way of doing it, and goes against specifically what he asked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try the [Architecture Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/create-layer-diagrams-from-your-code?view=vs-2019) (Visual Studio > Architecture > New Dependency Diagram) or a project like *[NDepend](http://ndepend.com)* (not free).

If you don't see the architecture menu in Visual Studio, you may need to [modify your installation](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/25007/architecture-menu-is-not-showing-for-vs-enterprise.html) to add the Architecture tools.

In Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, you can right click on your solution and select `Show Project Dependency Diagram` if you have *[ReShaper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)*.

Comment: If project is huge you can group projects in different folders having a clear dependancy hierarchy and you filter these  folders in the dependency diagram. If you can't spot quickly circular dependancies it is really worth making some order in the diagram.

Comment: Thanks for the very useful answer with several alternatives!

Comment: You can right click on your solution and select ```Select Project Dependency Diagram``` in VS Enterprise 2017 as well.

Comment: First link is down

Comment: @Hille Thanks for the heads up. I believe it originally linked to a project by a developer who now works on Visual Studio tools, so his project(s) have been rolled into new versions of VS.